# Differential Equation in space of complex-valued functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation
$$\Big[ \frac{d^2}{dx^2} - m^2 \Big] f(x) = \cos(x), m\in \mathbb{R}$$
in the space of complex-valued functions $f \in L^{1} (\mathbb{R}) \cap C^2(\mathbb{R})$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Questions posted here should not be written an a form suitable for assigning homework.  It can make people wonder if you copied a question without understanding it, when you didn't actually have a question in your own mind.

Comment: My try: I solve eigenvalue, eigenvector equation: $f^{''} -m^2 = \lambda f$ by solving homogenous equation first, my final solution is $f(x) =c_1 e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x} +c_2 e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} x} -\frac{1}{\lambda} x^2 -\frac{2}{\lambda}$ but i am not confident i wrote the eigenvalue eq correct

Comment: Your equation is $f''-m^2f=\cos x$. Find one particular solution, solve the homogeneous $f''-m^2f=0$, add the solutions together.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $m$ is not a few specialized values such as $m=\pm i$, the only possible solutions are
$$
           Ae^{-mx}+Be^{mx}-\frac{1}{1+m^{2}}\cos x
$$
So you're not going to get a solution in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: $m\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $m = \pm i$ won't give you solutions in $L^1$ either.